# Fail to conduct resistanceGA with run_gdistance

Tags: raster, r, distance-matrix, landscape

I am using a landscape surface resistance distance counting R packages called [resistanceGA](https://github.com/wpeterman/ResistanceGA)
It can count commuteDistance with the assistance of another package [gdistance](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgeos/versions/0.4-3/topics/gDistance)

It uses the following code to combine two of my resistance surfaces

```
variable1<-raster(file.choose())
variable2<-raster(file.choose())
r.stack<-stack(variable1,variable2)

#prepare the gdist input and ga input
GA.inputs <- GA.prep(ASCII.dir = r.stack,
Results.dir = write.dir,
method = "LL",
max.cat = 1000,
max.cont = 1000,
seed = 555,
parallel = 4)

gdist.inputs <- gdist.prep(length(samples),
samples = samples,
response = lower(as.matrix(genetic.distance)),
method = 'commuteDistance')
```

The samples is SpatialPoints objects and genetic.distance is my genetic distance matrix. Both work fine with [Circuitscape](https://circuitscape.org/), but not in the case of gdistance.

```
#and make transformation and combine
PARM <- c(8, 5, 100, 1, 1, 80)

Resist <- Combine_Surfaces(PARM = PARM,
CS.inputs  = CS.inputs,
GA.inputs = GA.inputs,
out = NULL,
p.contribution = TRUE)
Resist

gdist.response <- Run_gdistance(gdist.inputs = gdist.inputs,
+ r = Resist$combined.surface)
```

However, it returned error as following

```
Error in LU.dgC(a) : cs_lu(A) failed: near-singular A (or out of memory)
```

I have checked that none of my spatial points is in the NA cell.
If I change gdistance with CS_run or cs.inputs it works fine with Circuitscape.
Does one have idea how to solve this?

Comment: I am having the same problem. How did you solve it?